# Facebook Marketing API (#2654) Account Request Limits Reached, Sub Error Code:1870024

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-java-api

We've been using Facebook Marketing API v4.0. For an account, I keep getting error below. We cannot find any info about this sub error on Facebook docs. Our client deleted some Custom Audiences in their account but nothing changed.

```
{"error":
{"message":"(#2654) Account Request Limits Reached: You've reached the total number of times 
you can create a Custom Audience through one or more ad accounts in this business.",
"type":"OAuthException",
"code":2654,
"error_subcode":1870024,
"fbtrace_id":"AmN2PwJB8utcYZCXu2y-9TF"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the Changelog of the v4.0 API under `Breaking Changes
 - Ads Management` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version4.0#adsman):

> Updated the the rate limit for several areas under Marketing API. This includes:
>
> - custom_audience - Per each ad account in a one-hour time period:
>
>   - Standard Tier Apps: Minimum of 190000 + 40 * Number of Active custom audiences. Maximum of 700000.
>   - Dev Tier Apps: Minimum of 5000 + 40 * Number of Active custom audiences. Maximum of 700000.

You can also check the `Business Use Case Rate Limits` in the header of the response `X-Business-Use-Case-Usage` as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/#headers-2), like:

```
x-business-use-case-usage: {
    "{business-object-id}": [
        {
            "type": "{rate-limit-type}",           //Type of BUC rate limit logic being applied.
            "call_count": 100,                     //Percentage of calls made. 
            "total_cputime": 25,                   //Percentage of the total CPU time that has been used.
            "total_time": 25,                      //Percentage of the total time that has been used.   
            "estimated_time_to_regain_access": 19  //Time in minutes to regain access.
        }
    ],      
    "66782684": [
        {
            "type": "ads_management",
            "call_count": 95,
            "total_cputime": 20,
            "total_time": 20,
            "estimated_time_to_regain_access": 0
        }
    ],
    "10153848260347724": [
        {
            "type": "ads_management",
            "call_count": 97,
            "total_cputime": 23,
            "total_time": 23,
            "estimated_time_to_regain_access": 0
        }
    ],
...
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the info, we checked that but we can't create 50k custom audiences (2 days passed, first error occured) . And our app creates an empty custom audience list, then add phone numbers to that list.

Comment: @bek you can also check the header of the response for further info, like `X-Business-Use-Case-Usage`  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/#headers-2